# Attach one div to the right of another div, but flow to the next line

Tags: html, css

I would like to place 3 divs (or spans) with variable length text side by size so that the text reads as if it was in a single element. I found this post on how to [Attach div to the right of another div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31830089/attach-div-to-the-right-of-another-div). But if I follow the method in this post, it seems as if longer spans of text show up own their own new lines. I want the box on the bottom line to start directly to the right of the second box (from right) on the top line. **I want whatever text does not fit on the first line to continue on the second line.** I am not sure how to do this in CSS + HTML.

```
<div style="position: relative;">

    <div style="font-size: 14px; display: inline; border: 1px solid green; float: left;">Lorem us turpis inasdf aadsf aasda ss</div>
    <div style="font-size: 14px; display: inline; border: 1px solid green; float: left;">Lorem us turpis </div>
    <div style="font-size: 14px; display: inline; border: 1px solid green; float: left;">Lorem us turpis inasdf aadsf aasda ss</div>

</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily achieved by using `<span>` tags.  I switched out your `<div>` tags for `<span>` tags and placed all 3 spans inside a `<p>` tag.  This works with and without the `<p>` tag.  I separated the style into a class named `text` for better readability.  Lastly, I increased the font size so that the text is more likely to wrap on your screen and prove the point.

```css
.text {
    font-size: 25px; 
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative;">

            <p>
                <span class="text">Lorem us turpis inasdf aadsf aasda ss</span>
                <span class="text">Lorem us turpis</span>
                <span class="text">Lorem us turpis inasdf aadsf aasda ss</span>
            </p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `<span>` element, it shouldn't break, but rather wrap as you'd like.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a6fdkjvc/) tested in Safari and FF.

```css
.text {
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <span class="text">Lorem us turpis inasdf aadsf aasda ss</span>
    <span class="text">Lorem us turpis </span>
    <span class="text">Lorem us turpis inasdf aadsf aasda ss</span>
</div>
```

---

Further, if you want to use a `<div>` element, remove `position` on the container element, remove `float` on the child elements and simply add `display: inline`.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a6fdkjvc/1/)

```css
.text {
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="text">Lorem us turpis inasdf aadsf aasda ss</div>
    <div class="text">Lorem us turpis </div>
    <div class="text">Lorem us turpis inasdf aadsf aasda ss</div>
</div>
```